Can't find the 'Work' focus icon in SF Symbols
I'm looking for an SF Symbol to represent an administrator user etc, and I want something along the lines of the lanyardcard. The 'Work' focus icon is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't find it in SF Symbols, despite searching the full person category and trying many search terms.
Is the symbol listed? Am I allowed too use it? Is it intentionally excluded?
Any help appreciated!


This is a private symbol from /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SFSymbols.framework/Versions/A/Resources/CoreGlyphsPrivate.bundle
Here's how to get access to them on macOS:
extension NSImage {
    static func privateImage(systemSymbolName: String) -> NSImage? {
        let selector = NSSelectorFromString("imageWithPrivateSystemSymbolName:")
        return NSImage.perform(selector, with: systemSymbolName)?.takeUnretainedValue() as? NSImage
    }
}

let img = Image(nsImage: NSImage.privateImage(systemSymbolName: "person.lanyardcard.fill")!)
print(img)

The Work symbol name can be found in /System/Library/DoNotDisturb/DB/PlaceholderModes.json:
    {
      "semanticType": 4,
      "visibility": 2,
      "modeIdentifier": "com.apple.focus.work",
      "name": "Work",
      "identifier": "03EAF428-873F-11EB-8DCD-0242AC130003",
      "symbolImageName": "person.lanyardcard.fill",
      "tintColorName": "systemTealColor"
    },


A much better answer than mine.

Searched through SF Symbols v6.0.
It looks like it might have been achieved with some ZStack magic in SwiftUI as a combination of person.crop.square (and / or with .fill) and lanyardcard.fill, with appropriate settings for colour, scale and opacity.
Mind you, that's what it looks like to me. I don't know if that is actually possible - my SwiftUI skills are very minimal.
As to how this is applicable to your usage... are you using this in app development or require it for some other purpose? If the former, you might get more info with a query on SO. But be prepared with a worked example, as you know from your bio!
